# How do I publish/deploy an MVC Project with ResX Resources?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, localization, resx

I have written a VERY simple MVC application which just displays a single string from a Resource file.  It works just fine on my local machine but when I deploy the project to the web server I get the error.

> CS0103: The name 'Resources' does not
>   exist in the current context

You can very easily replicate exactly what I am doing in just 10 steps!

1. **Create a New MVC 2 Web Application.**
   (File->New->Project->ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application, say no to the Unit Testing Project)
2. **Add the "App_GlobalResources" folder.**
   (right click the project and select Add->Add ASP.NET Folder->App_GlobalResources)
3. **Add a Resource File to this folder.**
   (right click the folder and select Add->New Item...->Resources File.  Name it Strings.resx)
4. **Add a single string to the Resource table.**
   (Name = "HelloWorld", Value = "I localized Hello World!")
5. **Set the File Properties for the Resource File.**
   (Click the file Strings.resx and int the Properties window set Build Action = "Embedded Resource" and the CustomTool = "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator")
6. **Add a new Controller**
   (Right click the Controllers folder and select Add->Controller...  Name it HelloWorldController.cs)
7. **Add a the View**
   (With the cursor in the Index method of the HelloWorldController.cs Press CTRL-M-V.  Use the default values including View name = "Index")
8. **Modify the View so that it displays our string from the resource file.**
   Replace the content of the MainContent placeholder with

   ```
   <h2><%: Resources.Strings.HelloWorld %></h2>
   ```
9. **Run it locally to test that it works.**  Which it should.
10. **Publish it to a web server and visit the url "http://localhost/HelloWorld"**

This is where I see the error described at the top.

I would imagine that the settings I've put on the ResX file are incorrect and the resource is not published to the server.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ah ha!  Figured it out.  In LARGE part to this article:
http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx

Sounds like the App_GlobalResources folder is NOT cooperative with MVC.  So I moved my ResX file to a new folder
**~/Resources/Strings**/Strings.resx

This along with 1 minor change to set the File Property
**Custom Tool Namespace** = Resources

and Problem Solved!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was bugging me and the answer was presented to me when I was trying to post a question on here.